# ActiveCell.Formula + String

Tags: excel, vba

I have inside a string a dynamic variable that is mounted by a for through an ODBC connection, but when I try to put it as a formula, it fails me.

```
VariableString = "Informe - "& TEXT(C9;"aaaa/mm/dd") &" - "& TEXT(G9;"aaaa/mm/dd")
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & VariableString
```

How could you do it to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: What formula do you expect to be in the ActiveCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking it that the formula you want in the active cell is
`="Informe - " & TEXT(C9;"aaaa/mm/dd") & " - " & TEXT(G9;"aaaa/mm/dd")`
this will display something like:
`Informe - 2017/01/01 - 2017/02/01`

Currently your code thinks that C9 and G9 are VBA variables and not cell references due to not doubling up your quotes.

Use:

```
VariableString = "=""Informe - "" & Text(R9C3,""yyyy/mm/dd"") & "" - "" & Text(R9C7,""yyyy/mm/dd"")"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1Local = VariableString
```

I've updated your cell references to R1C1 style as I find them easier to write in VBA.

Edit:  You may have to update the `,` to `;` and `yyyy` to `aaaa`.  No idea if `FormulaR1C1Local` changes them to the correct format for your regional settings.

Comment: True, do not change the format of the date. I am sorry. He changed FormulaR1C1Local by FormulaR1C1 and it worked correctly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a reference from that string you can use:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDIRECT(" & VariableString & ")"
```